# Close Browser after Navigation Timeout

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have this code below made with nodejs + puppeteer, whose goal is to take a screenshot of the user's site:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://MY_WEBSITE/try/slowURL',{timeout: 30000, waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });//timeout 30 seconds
await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
await page.screenshot({path: pathUpload});
await browser.close();
```

Its operation is quite simple, but to test the timeout I created a page (`http://MY_WEBSITE/try/slowURL`) that takes 200 seconds to load.

According to the puppeteer timeout (`timeout: 30000`), there is a 100% chance of a **Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded error** happening, especially because I'm forcing it.

**THE PROBLEM**

Through the `htop` command (used in linux), even after the system crashes and shows **"TimeoutError"**, I can see that the browser has not been closed.

And if the browser is not closed, as scans were done, there is a good chance that the server will run out of memory, and I don't want that.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to wrap your code into a [`try..catch..finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#The_finally_clause) statement to handle the error and close the browser.

**Code Sample**

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(/* ... */);
    // more code which might throw...
} catch (err) {
    console.error('error', err.message);
} finally {
    await browser.close();
}
```

Your main code is executed inside  a `try` block. The `catch` block shows any kind of error that might happened. The `finally` part is the part of your script that is always executed, not only when an error is thrown. That way, independent of whether an error happened or not, your script will call the `browser.close` function.

Comment: The `finally` block is definitely the place where to close the `browser` instance.
I kept having memory leak issues, albeit less, until I added a `await page.close();` before closing the browser